# Accessing Javascript arrays and objects

Tags: javascript

Here i have an object like this :

```
fruits = { a: 'apple' , b: 'banana'};
```

and array like this:

```
array = ['a', 'b'];
```

then i want the array like this:

```
array = ['apple', 'banana'];
```

Comment: Your array is not valid.

Comment: If **fruits** is a dictionary use this: `array = array.map(a => fruits[a])`.

Answer (score 4):

firstly, you have a typo in your first snippet, js objects employ `{}`'s, e.g. `fruits = {a: 'apple', b: 'banana'};`.

to answer your question, you essentially want to map one array to another (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics) explains the concept)
The javascript syntax for doing so looks like:

`let array2 = array.map(a => fruits[a])`

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) wikipedia page is more appropriate :)

Comment: Why not just the MDN docs for [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?